# Properties of measurable functions on Banach spaces?

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces

I'm looking for references on the topic of measurable functions on Banach spaces. Specifically, if $X$ and $Y$ are "nice" Banach spaces (separable, etc.) endowed with $\sigma$-algebras so that $(X,\Sigma)$ and $(Y, \text{T})$ are measurable spaces, what are the properties of measurable functions $f : (X,\Sigma)\to(Y,\text{T})$? I assume the scalar multiple & sum of measurable functions is itself measurable (though I haven't checked if this is true, I just assumed the proofs would be similar enough to the proofs for measurable real valued functions), but what about other properties? Things I'm interested in are:

> If $f$ is measurable, and $A\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ is linear and continuous (equivalently bounded), is $f\circ A$ measurable? What if $A$ is compact?
>
> If $f$ is measurable, is $\|f\| : (X,\Sigma)\to\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ measurable (with respect to Borel sets or Lebesgue measurable sets on $\mathbb{R}$)?
>
> If $Y$ is a Banach algebra, and $f$ and $g$ are measurable, then is $fg$ measurable?

I've found it surprisingly difficult to find resources on these topics, topics which I thought would've been pretty standard functional analysis topics. What are some good resources to learn about these things?

Comment: Certainly none of these properties will be true if you don't make some assumptions about the $\sigma$-algebras $\Sigma$ and $T$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I must admit I'm more familiar with functional analysis than measure theory, I just started diving into it this week, and I was just curious about extending some of the properties of Lebesgue measurable functions. So I'm not too keen on what properties the $\sigma$-algebras would need to possess in order for things to work out nicely.

Comment: And conversely, I think they will all be true if the $\sigma$-algebras are generated by the norm topologies. (Though I might need to give this more thought.)

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist That's what I was thinking, it seems reasonable enough of an assumption. Probably something wonky in the infinite dimensional case though.

Comment: Also, all Banach spaces are Hausdorff, so no need to assume that additionally for the space to be “nice”.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Right, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Having thought a bit more about it, the measurability of sums and scalar multiples of measurable functions makes strong use of properties of $\mathbb R$. If the $\sigma$-algebras are Borel (generated from the norm topologies), then the first two properties you state follow from the facts that continuous functions are measurable, and that composition of measurable functions preserves measurability. I don’t know about the third property.